# How can I use .htaccess to respond with 403 forbidden status for URLs that contain a query string?

Tags: htaccess, apache, 403-forbidden, query-string

Some bots have been crawling my site for every link that ends with:

```
?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter
```

I haven't checked out its IP.

Then other bots (10+) follow the link rules `?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter` and also crawl my site. This results in a huge amount of traffic which then causes my site to shut down. I have added 10+ other bots into my blacklist with an HTTP `403` status code when they access my site.

But I think the best way is to find out the first bot which crawled my site for every link that ends with:

```
?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter
```

Or,  use a an HTTP `403` redirect status code when the URL contains:

```
?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter
```

I know of some ways to add *.htaccess* code that would prevent someone from crawling my `xmlrpc.php` page, such as:

```
<Files xmlrpc.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</Files>
```

But what about a query in URL?

Comment: Are you sure that `utm_source` and `utm_medium` are not required? They are typically used by Google Analytics to track campaigns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the *mod_rewrite* module installed, then you can put this in your *.htaccess* file in the root folder of your website (which usually is the `public_html` folder):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\?utm_source\=dlvr.it\&utm_medium\=twitter$ - [R=403,NC,L]
```

You might have to remove the `\` from the `=`, I can't remember if equals needs escaping.

Another way would be this if you're searching for the string anywhere in the URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?utm_source\=dlvr.it\&utm_medium\=twitter(.*)$ - [R=403,NC,L]
```

The `NC` at the end means not case-sensitive, so if the text is all upper-case, then the bots would be directed to an error `403`.

Comment: Did the OP actually try this? This cannot work, unless the query string is not actually a query string and the `?` is %-encoded in the request? The query string is removed from the URL-path before pattern matching.

Comment: I think rules in mod_rewrite take precedence over just standard files. That's why I posted that answer. One nice thing about that module is that you can make non-existing folders appear to the end user as real folders on the system. For example, To make the end user think folder abc exists in the root of the website and make your own file manager that displays contents of it inside PHP, put this line in .htaccess `RewriteRule ^abc$ /somefile.php?folder=abc [L]` where somefile.php is the script that does the processing.

Comment: Hi @w3d, so how about use `SetEnvIf Request_URI "(?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter)" banned` `Deny from env=banned` in htaccess?

Comment: @spaceandtime That wouldn't work either, the query string (I assume this is an ordinary query string on the request?) is omitted from `Request_URI` - the same reason why the above mod_rewrite directives won't work (although there are also other issues with the regex). (Although you've marked the answer as "accepted" and not stated anything to the contrary, which implies that this does work for you?)

Answer (score 7):

> ?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter

`utm_source` and `utm_medium` are used by Google Analytics (and possibly other trackers) to monitor campaigns, so blocking access purely on this query string does not "feel right", however, if this is correct in your situation then ok...

An important point to realise with *query strings* is that they cannot be matched using mod_rewrite's `RewriteRule` directive (or using the `Request_URI` variable in mod_setenvif - as suggested in comments). The `RewriteRule` directive (as with the `Request_URI` variable) matches against the URL-path only, which notably excludes the query string.

Enable the rewrite engine (mod_rewrite) if not already:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

You need to use the `RewriteCond` directive and match against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable. So, in order to serve a "403 Forbidden" for all requests that match the above query string *exactly* then you can use something like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

The `=` prefix on the *CondPattern* performs an *exact* string match for the specified query string (it's not a regex, so the *dot* does not need to be escaped). The `L` flag is not required when specifying the `F` flag (it is implied). (`F` is shorthand for `R=403`.)

If you need it to be less restrictive and match all query strings that just starts with the above query string then use a regex:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm_source=dlvr\.it&utm_medium=twitter
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Or, any query string that contains both the URL parameters `utm_source=dlvr.it` and `utm_medium=twitter` but in any order and anywhere in the query string (including additional/optional URL parameters) then you can split the check into two *conditions*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)utm_source=dlvr\.it(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)utm_medium=twitter(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

You can also make the regex case-insensitive by using the `NC` (`nocase`) flag on the `RewriteCond` directive. However, only use this if you specifically need to ignore case in the match. People tend to append this flag out of habit, however, it's often unnecessary (or sometimes even incorrect) and just makes the regex engine work that bit harder.

This is not particularly efficient since every request will be processed. If, for instance, only the URLs within the `/path/to/files` path is targeted then you could make the `RewriteRule` pattern more restrictive:

```
:
RewriteRule ^path/to/files/ - [F]
```