# Redirecting "ugly" urls to pretty ones?

Tags: htaccess, apache, apache2

For example to display `/id/123` for `/urlugly?id=123` I can do

```
RewriteRule ^id/([^/]*)$ /urlugly?id=$1 [L]
```

and apparently for redirect I can add [R]

```
RewriteRule ^id/([^/]*)$ /urlugly?id=$1 [R,L]
```

which redirects /id/123 **to** /urlugly?id=123 as expected.

if I wanted to redirect /urlugly?id=123 to /id/123 I thought

```
RewriteRule ^urlugly?id=$ /id/([^/]*)$1  [R]
RewriteRule ^id/([^/]*)$ /urlugly?id=$1 [L]
```

This would work... and I have tried some other similiar things, and  I think my logic here is correct, but its obviously not.

So How do I redirect `/urlugly?id=123` to /`id/123`? I can't seem to get it to work. I know (think?) [L] means "ignore others that match this" and I think it applies to the ones that are -below- that line with [L]

i.e. if I put [R] above that it would still work and [L] would also work... Is this correct?

What am I doing wrong here and what is the correct approach?

Comment: You can't use `RewriteRule` to match the query string, you need to use `RewriteCond`. See: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/77266/1243 However, you also need to be careful of creating a rewrite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to rewrite your pretty URLs to a handler while at the same time redirecting ugly URLs for the handler back to the pretty URL.  I had to [ask how to do it at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340785/how-to-rewrite-to-a-script-and-also-redirect-away-from-that-script-using-htacce).

mod_rewrite makes multiple passes over your rules, so specifying the `[L]` flag is not enough. When you rewrite your pretty URL your need to set an environment variable.   Then when you decide whether to redirect an ugly URL, only do so when the environment variable is not set (so that you avoid redirecting when it is only ugly because of your rewrite.)   On the second pass when this redirect is evaluated, environment variables are all prefixed with `REDIRECT_`.  So if you set a `LOOP` environment variable, you have to read it as `REDIRECT_LOOP`.   Here is what should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^id/([^/]*)$ /urlugly?id=$1 [L,E=LOOP:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_LOOP} !1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(.+)
RewriteRule ^urlugly$ /id/%1 [R,L]
```

Comment: See also: [Remove extension from URL using a rewrite without resulting in a redirect loop](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68577/remove-extension-from-url-using-a-rewrite-without-resulting-in-a-redirect-loop) which uses the same technique.

Comment: Another common way to prevent rewrite loops is to check against `%{THE_REQUEST}`, which only ever contains the original request, not the rewritten URL. eg. `GET /urlugly?id=123 HTTP/1.1`. If `THE_REQUEST` contains "urlugly" then "urlugly" has been directly requested, so redirect to the _pretty URL_. This avoids having to set and check for environment variables.